# How can I change the order of icons in Wingpanel?

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel

I installed a weather applet and a system monitoring applet yesterday, and I was wondering if it was possible to change the order of the icons on Wingpanel.

I.e. I would like to place the weather applet between the system-monitoring applet and the language icon on the picture below. Is there an easy way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure it is not possible without rewriting Wingpanel.
You can propose your wish at the [Wingpanel bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel), and if the developers like your idea, they may consider implementing it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

### Please note that this works for all indicators and *not just* application indicators. A few exceptions may not be adjustable.

According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26114/is-it-possible-to-change-the-order-of-icons-in-the-indicator-applet) ask Ubuntu, it is possible:

- First:

  `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/indicators/application
  cp /usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile ~/.local/share/indicators/application/`

  - Indicator order is determined by a keyfile. These commands create such a keyfile for your user account.
- Then:

  `scratch-text-editor ~/.local/share/indicators/application/ordering-override.keyfile`
- The order of the indicators is determined by their corresponding number.
- Lower numbers, mean higher priorities, which means these will be closer to the right of the panel.
- You can add any indicator to the list and assign it a priority.
- To set the order for a custom indicator, just add the name of its executable to the list and give it a custom priority.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/343886/1992
Further reading: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/how-to-change-application-indicators.html

Comment: Anyone tested this method?

Comment: I haven't, but it should work. If I'm not mistaken, Wingpanel works essentially the same as Unity in this regard.

Comment: As indicated by Ted in the original post, this is for *application* indicators, not system indicators

Comment: I think you should edit your answer and explain what do these commands do exactly.

Comment: @DanielForé as far as I'm aware this affects all indicators.

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone actually tested it if it works?
I tried this method now on LOKI and it doesn't seem to work.

```
[Ordering Index Overrides]
nm-applet=1
gnome-power-manager=2
ibus=3
gst-keyboard-xkb=4
gsd-keyboard-xkb=5
my-weather-indicator=6
indicator-sensors=7
Telegram=8
megasync=9
```

[image]

If I messed something up, help is appreciated.

Comment: Likewise in Juno. I'm almost liable to download an older release and try it in a VM to see if I'm actually following the directions right.