# Is there a way to reorder systray indicator icons?

Tags: wingpanel, settings, notifications, notification-badge

I have a hard disk free space indicator icon in the notification area that I would like to move. Is there a way to do that in elementary?

THANKS!!

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/600/37

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do that. The ordering of the indicators is hard-coded, as you can see [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wingpanel-devs/wingpanel/trunk/view/head:/src/Services/IndicatorSorter.vala#L29).